# How to check if a Model connected to the table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-blade

I have a custom Model which I generated with `php artisan make:model`.
I want to know if my custom model is connected to the table in my database because I try to show the field using `Datatables` but it doesn't show the field and I don't get any error.

**My model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Hr\Models;

use App\Models\Model;
use DB;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = "employee";

    protected $primaryKey = "nik";

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        "nik",
        "employee_name",
        "idaddress",
        "dom_address",
        "hpno",
        "email",
        "gender",
        "npwp",
        "birthdate",
        "identity_no",
        "join_date",
        "blood_type",
        "is_active",
        "end_date",
        "birthplace",
        "postalcode",
        "districts",
        "propcode",
        "citycode",
        "religioncode",
        "statuscode",
        "doc_npwp",
        "photo",
        "doc_id",
        //
    ];
}
```

**My controller**

```
public function index(){
    return view([
        "model" => new Employee,
    ]);
}

public function data(){
    return Datatables::of(Employee::select("*"))->make(true);
}
```

**My view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" datatable="{{ url("hr/employee/data") }}">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th dt-field="nik"> {{ $model->label("nik") }} </th>
        {{-- <th dt-field="unit_kind"> {{ $model->label("unit_kind") }} </th> --}}
      <th dt-field="employee_name"> {{ $model->label("employee_name") }} </th>
      <th dt-field="idaddress"> {{ $model->label("idaddress") }} </th>
      <th dt-field="dom_address"> {{ $model->label("dom_address") }} </th>
      <th dt-col="#dt-action" sort="false" search="false"> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Is there any way to check if my model is connected to the table?

Comment: Why not just create a record and then check the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel by default will try to find a table whose name is snake case plural name of Model class..

for e.g :- for Model "Flight" , it will look for table "flights"

however you can prevent this default approach by specifying the table_name inside the model

for e.g:- protected $table_name = "my_flights"

hope this helps

Comment: [The property is `$table`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), not `$table_name`, and OP has it correctly in his posted code.